# Would it be possible to note similarities with in comparison with?

Tags: comparatives

*In comparison with* is used to show contrasting ideas. I wonder whether this phrase could be used to note similarities as well, especially with words like: similar, the same, alike. Would you, for example, consider the following?
*In comparison with each other, both of the girls seem similar.*

Answer (score 1):

Actually, comparison involves noting the **similarities or** differences between things.

English teachers in fact sometimes ask their students to "**compare and contrast**" things, where the former term is contrasted (!) with the latter: the latter develops differences, whereas the former can develop similarities.

That said, the example you gives is not a good use of this meaning of `compare`, mainly because it just refers to similarity in general.  If you were to really compare the two by pointing to similarities, then to be useful you would want the exposition of similarities to be specific. E.g., saying that they both had red hair and brown eyes compares them.  Saying that they are similar is not much of a comparison.

Comment: So if I reworded my example to become as follows, would the sentence be considered natural? In comparison with each other, both of the girls have the same hair color, height, etc... .

Comment: I don't see your reworded sentence.  See my example for a natural comparison that points out similarities.  Just point out *particular* similarities, instead of just stating generally that they are similar.

Comment: I see it now. For some reason I was not seeing your whole comment. Yes, that's it. (But you can leave off "both of".)